# ModSecurity count the number of hosts accessed by an IP

Tags: apache, webserver, firewall, mod-security, mod-security2

I need to block the ip addresses which access to more than 3 domains at the same time using ModSecurity
For example if some ip accessed:

```
domain1.com/someuri234
domain2.com/someuri2342
domain3.com/someuri534535
domain1.com/someuri234234
domain5.com/someuri234234
```

Then we block it
So we need to count the number of domains and check for it
appreciate for any help

Comment: I'm not sure this is a ModSecurity task. If you're using Apache, it's better to use mod_qos or mod_evasive.

Comment: @airween We need to count the number of hosts per ip, Do you think we can do using initcol:ip=%{SERVER_NAME}

Comment: @airween I used mod_evasive , it uses much resources and I think it doesn't work great

Comment: @airween May be we can store data using initcol:RESOURCE=%{SERVER_NAME}

Comment: My opinion is still this is not a ModSec task :). You can try to use the collections, but don't forget to clear them (with use of `expirevar`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could implement this scenario using `exec:/script.sh` and send request information through `setenv` and then collect request data and analys them on the script and block ip addresses using firewall

```
SecAction "id:1233456,phase:1,nolog,pass,\
    setenv:RQ_REMOTE_HOST=%{REMOTE_HOST},\
    setenv:RQ_REMOTE_ADDR=%{REMOTE_ADDR},\
    setenv:RQ_SERVER_NAME=%{SERVER_NAME},\
    setenv:RQ_SERVER_ADDR=%{SERVER_ADDR},\
    setenv:RQ_SERVER_PORT=%{SERVER_PORT},\
    setenv:RQ_REQUEST_URI=%{REQUEST_URI},\
    setenv:RQ_REQUEST_LINE=%{REQUEST_LINE},\
    setenv:RQ_SCRIPT_FILENAME=%{SCRIPT_FILENAME},\
    setenv:RQ_SCRIPT_USERNAME=%{SCRIPT_USERNAME},\
    setenv:RQ_USERAGENT=%{REQUEST_HEADERS.User-Agent},\
    exec:/script.sh"
```